# Why red5 and tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, integration, red5, seek

Yes I noticed that red5 sometimes would not be normal, especially when I tried seek() too many times in very short interval. But I was wondering if I deploy the whole red5 to tomcat, what kind of advantages can I get? Also what kind of bad things I might encounter? Thank you.

---

Rewritten question:

Sorry. Here is my situation. We have a client written in Flex, which could play streamed audio/video from a red5 server. Because none of my team is very familiar with red5, basically we just run red5 server directly through bash shell. It makes me feel that through this way we can not exploit the advantages of red5. Also we have a problem when seeking the audio/video too many time, the player becomes jammed. Also  we have to restart the red5 server very often, because of jammed player too. So I searched for solution and I noticed someone deploys the red5 to a tomcat server but not saying why doing this. So my question is about the advantages and disadvantage of deploying red5 to tomcat. That's it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to re-write your question with a lot more detail. If you aren't deploying to Tomcat, tell us what you are deploying to. If you are only partially-deploying to Tomcat (whatever that means), please describe that, too. What does "red5 sometimes would not be normal" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Red5 installs itself inside of an instance of Tomcat(which it installs also). You don't need to put it there. You can start it as a service - there are plenty of sample scripts to put in /etc/init.d available.

Edit the config files so it will log all of the errors. Then see why it's getting 'jammed'.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 can be added to any web or Java EE project:

Step 1: Download and Un-Zip the Red5War_1.0.war or later

Step 2: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source" folder of the Project.

Step 3: Navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and paste in "Libraries" folder of the Project.

Step 4: Copy the contents of configuration files to your project (like web.xml...)

Step 5: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Request: Please share your findings.